# Help to identify chinese seals on 2 paintings

Tags: character-identification, seal

Here is 2 others asian paintings that I own from which I totally ignore the artist's name and would be happy to know it.

Painting 1:

[image]
[image]

Painting 2:

[image]

Thank you for your help so far!